# If we make a number every millisecond, how much data would we have in a day?

Tags: database, math, database-design

I'm a bit confused here... I'm being offered to get into a project, where would be an array of certain sensors, that would give off reading every millisecond ( yes, 1000 reading in a second ). Reading would be a 3 or 4 digit number, for example like 818 or 1529. This reading need to be stored in a database on a server and accessed remotely.

I never worked with such big amounts of data, what do you think, how much in terms of MBs reading from one sensor for a day would be?... 4(digits)x1000x60x60x24 ... = 345600000 bits ... right ? about 42 MB per day... doesn't seem too bad, right?

therefor a DB of, say, 1 GB, would hold 23 days of info from 1 sensor, correct?

I understand that MySQL & PHP probably would not be able to handle it... what would you suggest, maybe some aps? azure? oracle?

Comment: Your comment about "MySQL & PHP probably would not be able to handle it" is a bit ambiguous. Most modern RDBMS systems can handle "tall" tables--that is, tables with lots of rows with few columns--without too many problems. However, with the amount of writing you'll have to do to support that kind of throughput, I'd be far more concerned about hardware I/O.

Comment: As for writing, I guess data could be stored on some local memory and dumped into the DB, say, every 10 minutes or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 or 4 digit number =

```
4 bytes if you store it as a string.
2 bytes storing it as a 16bit (0-65535) integer

1000/sec -> 60,000/minute -> 3,600,000/hour, 86,400,000/day

as string: 86,400,000 * 4 bytes = 329megabytes/day
as integer:86,400,000 * 2bytes = 165megabytes/day
```

Your DB **may** not perform too well under that kind of insert load, especially if you're running frequent selects on the same data. optimizing a DB for largescale retrieval slows things down for fast/frequent inserts. On the other hand, inserting a simple integer is not exactly a "stressful" operation.

You'd probably be better off inserting into a temporary database, and do an hourly mass copy into the main 'archive' database. You do your analysis/mining on that main archive table, with the understanding that its data will be up to 1 hour stale.

But in the end, you'll have to benchmark variations of all this and see what works best for your particular usage case. There's no "you must do X to achieve Y" type advice in databaseland.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you will need not to keep the data with such a high discretization for a long time. You may use several options to minimize the volumes. First, after some period of time you may collapse hourly data into min/max/avg values; you may keep detailed info only for some unstable situations detected or situations that require to keep detailed data by definition. Also, many things may be turned into events logging. These approaches were implemented and successfully used a couple of decades ago in some industrial automation systems provided by the company I have been working for at that time. The available storage devices sizes were times smaller than you can find today.

So, first, you need to analyse the data you will be storing and then decide how to optimize it's storage.

Comment: you're right, if data patters is "normal", then such data is mostly now needed and can be, probably, stored, say, 1 minute from every hours. And would be stored "full time", only if the patters looks abnormal.

Answer (score 1):

Following @MarcB's numbers, 2 bytes at 1kHz, is just 2KB/s, or 16Kbit/s. This is not really too much of a problem.

I think a sensible and flexible approach should be to construct a queue of sensor readings which the database can simply pop until it is clear. At these data rates, the problem is not the throughput (which could be handled by a dial-up modem) but the gap between the timings. Any system caching values will need to be able to get out of the way fast enough for the next value to be stored; 1ms is not long to return, particularly if you have GC interference.

The advantage of a queue is that it is cheap to add something to the queue at one end, and the values can be processed in bulk at the other end. So the sensor end gets the responsiveness it needs and the database gets to process in bulk.

Answer (score 1):

İf you do not need relational database you can use a NoSQL database like mongodb or even a much simper solution like [JDBM2](http://code.google.com/p/jdbm2/), if you are using java.